# Browser unable to connect after removing ssl in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I were enabled SSL and every thing works fine. But when I disabled SSL and , the browser refuse to connect.

This image shows my configuration.
[image]

Another thing that make me confuse is that when the application is start running, the browser goes to the correct URL (which it is http://localhost:8080/), but when the error page is shown the URL become https://locathost

This image shows the problem:
[image]

I try deleting the applicationhost file, but it doesn't work.